# Keep getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I stuck with a problem. After an hour to search I am still working on this problem. I went through most of questions here but none of them works for me. It feels like I missed something simple.

This is my error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `client_infos_path' for # 
.  <#<Class:0x007fda7a69b160>:0x007fda7a6994a0>
Did you mean?  client_session_path
           client_path
           clients_path):
   1: <h2>Add <%= current_user.username%> info</h2>
   2:
   3: <%= form_for @client_info do |f| %>
   4:   <div class="field">
   5:     <%= f.label :company_size, 'Company Size' %> <br />
   6:     <%= f.text_field :company_size %>

app/views/client_infos/new.html.erb:3:in 
app_views_client_infos_new_html_erb__493536261245691520_70288166673800'
```

Here is my controller

```
class ClientInfosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_user

  def new
   # binding.pry
   @client_info = ClientInfo.new
   @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
  end
```

And my `routes.rb`

```
resources :clients do
  resources :projects
  resources :client_infos, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `client_infos_path' for

You have *nested resources* with `client_infos` under `clients`, so there isn't such route available for you. You need to change

```
<%= form_for @client_info do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for [@client, @client_info] do |f| %>
```

**Hint:**

Run `rake routes`. It will list out all available routes for you.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I was trying with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `rake routes` in your console, you will get:

```
        client_projects GET    /clients/:client_id/projects(.:format)              projects#index
                        POST   /clients/:client_id/projects(.:format)              projects#create
     new_client_project GET    /clients/:client_id/projects/new(.:format)          projects#new
    edit_client_project GET    /clients/:client_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format)     projects#edit
         client_project GET    /clients/:client_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#show
                        PATCH  /clients/:client_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
                        PUT    /clients/:client_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#update
                        DELETE /clients/:client_id/projects/:id(.:format)          projects#destroy
    client_client_infos POST   /clients/:client_id/client_infos(.:format)          client_infos#create
 new_client_client_info GET    /clients/:client_id/client_infos/new(.:format)      client_infos#new
                clients GET    /clients(.:format)                                  clients#index
                        POST   /clients(.:format)                                  clients#create
             new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                              clients#new
            edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                         clients#edit
                 client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#show
                        PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#update
                        PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#update
                        DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#destroy
```

As you can see, you don't have a `client_infos` path, because `client_infos` is nested under `clients`. Instead, you have `client_client_infos` - which is what you should be doing given your `routes.rb`. You can also do it like (as discussed in [2.9 Creating Paths and URLs From Objects](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)):

```
<%= form_for [@client, @client_info] do |f| %>
```

And Rails will infer that you want to use the `client_client_infos` named route.